# Get the latest added line of opened file

Tags: python, file

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
say = file.readline()
```

can I get the last line added by another process to this file without close/reopen it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See. I doubt this is possible because of the fact that when you use fopen, and "write" some data into the files, they aren't really written into the file. They are instead stored in a temporary buffer for the time being. On calling the fclose only are they actually transferred from the buffer to the file. So say another program of yours is using the file, it isn't just going to update itself in front of you everytime the other program has written something in it. When the program closes the file, then you simply open the file (or close it if already opened and open it again) and read the new content. When you open a file, a copy of the current version of the file is presented to you. So when somebody edits it, it isn't just going to change in in front of you. You need to close it, and then when you open it again, python will go and fetch the new edited file and show it to you.